# Show paragraph element based on whether image element was loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this image element.

```
<img src={{this.vac-card.vac_card_url}} alt="vac-card.png" id="vac-card-image" onerror="this.style.display='none'">

<p><a href={{url}} target="_blank">Click here to download.</a></p>
```

You can see that if the image does not load up properly, it will show nothing. How do I have it so that the paragraph only shows if the image did not load up, but it will not show if the image loaded properly?

Answer (score 2):

I would make the `p` element hidden by default, then attach an event listener to the "error" event of the image, in which I will show the paragraph.

```js
let img = document.getElementById("vac-card-image");
let paragraph = document.getElementById("my-paragraph");
img.addEventListener("error", () => paragraph.style.display = "block");
```

```css
p { display: none }
```

```html
<img src={{this.vac-card.vac_card_url}} alt="vac-card.png" id="vac-card-image" onerror="this.style.display='none'">

<p id="my-paragraph"><a href={{url}} target="_blank">Click here to download.</a></p>
```

Comment: Well, that would be so if it did what the op wants it to, but it does not. It throws an error about not knowing what that `src` attribute is. This does not perform the actions you describe in your answer for that reason. Specifically, after it throws the syntax error, it still shows the `<p>` element.